# Lentidão no carregamento dos arquivos dentro da pasta static no Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

Estou aprendendo Django e reparei que os arquivos estáticos demoram pra carregar, exemplo; eu tenho um arquivo css que define o estilo da home, eu mudo a cor da fonte e atualizo a pagina e nada acontece, depois de 2 minutos a cor da fonte muda. Isso é normal no Django?

Comment: Muito difícil te responder sem ver o código pois depende muito do que a sua aplicação está fazendo, por exemplo, se você está somente exibindo um html para o usuário isso não é normal, no entanto vamos supor que você estivesse criando uma API de machine learning, o django iria precisar carregar todo o seu modelo para depois sim exibir a página com a fonte alterada. O importante mesmo é você verificar os logs no seu terminal quando você termina de fazer uma alteração e verificar se a demora é plausível baseado no que está sendo exibido para você.

Comment: Eu não estou usando nenhuma API, apenas carregando uma pagina simples. No terminal, aparece isso: ```[16/Jul/2019 12:40:29] "GET /static/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0``` aparece na cor azul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eudson, ao acessar e ver o código 304, significa que o arquivo não foi modificado, por este motivo, é carregado o que esta em cache, quando isto ocorrer, basta que você pressione Control + F5, isto irá carregar todos os arquivos de seu site novamente, fazendo com que o arquivo style.css seja carregado novamente, ao fazer isto, você verá o código 200.

Comment: Isso resolveu o problema, mas não entendi essa parte de "arquivo não foi modificado", eu modifiquei o arquivo estático, a pagina deveria atualizar automaticamente. Porém ela carregava as mudanças com delay.

Comment: Arquivos carregados no browser são armazenados no cache, isto ocorre muito com imagens e css, se você substituir uma imagem na pasta static por outra sem renomear, por exemplo, ao atualizar a pagina, carregará a imagem antiga. Os arquivos css também são armazenados em cache, por este motivo, quando pressiona F5, é lido o que esta no cache, quando você pressiona Control + F5, é ignorado o que está no cache e uma nova copia é "baixada" do servidor local.